# Generate programmed data & create data frame out of it (generated data in to single column)

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

Initial context was, I was using "for loop" and generating some random data (using some logic shown below) and then writing that data to a key ('server_avg_response_time') in dictionary('data_dict'). Finally., that's a list('data_rows') of dictionaries and writing the whole to CSV.

**Code snippet for generating random data:**

```
server_avg_response_time_alert = "low"
for i in range(0,no_of_rows):
    if (random.randint(0,10) != 7 and server_avg_response_time_alert != "high"):
            data_dict['server_avg_response_time'] = random.randint(1,800000)

    else:
            if(server_avg_response_time_alert == "low"):
                    print "***ALERT***"
                    server_avg_response_time_alert = "high"

            data_dict['server_avg_response_time'] = random.randint(600000,800000)
            server_avg_response_time_period = random.randint(1,1000)
            if(server_avg_response_time_period > 980):
                    print "***ALERT OFF***"
                    server_avg_response_time_alert = "low"


    data_rows.insert(i,data_dict.copy())
```

This is taking lot of time (to generate some 300 000 rows of data) and hence I was asked to look for Pandas (to generate data fastly). Now, I am trying to use the same logic to pandas dataframe.

**Question**:  If I put above code in a function, can't I use that function to mint data in to column of dataframe? What is the best way to program this data in to a column of dataframe? I believe I don't need a dictionary (key) too if putting data directly to dataframe after generating it randomly. But don't know the syntax to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your logic (everything after the for loop) in a function, then pass that to an empty pandas df with one column called 'avg_resp_time'  (with 30000 rows) like this using the `apply` method:

```
def randomLogic(value):
    random_value = 0 # logic goes here
    return random_value

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(300000), columns=['server_avg_response_time'])

df['server_avg_response_time'] = df.server_avg_response_time.apply(randomLogic)
```